# Warning message "no argument after \section" in Texlipse

Tags: titlesec, warnings, texlipse

I have been trying to get a particular format for section headings in `Texlipse` using the following code.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\bfseries\filcenter}
{\S\thesection}{1em}{}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
```

But I don't get the output in the required format. Moreover, I get a warning message

```
No argument following \section
```

Any clues?.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also, what is the required output?

Comment: I imagine the "warning message" is specific to Texlipse, and not something you get from TeX during compile. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a problem due to TeXlipse trying to be smart, but it doesn't distinguishing when `\section` is used in a macro definition in the preamble or in the `document` environment.

You might be able to trick TeXlipse into not “seeing” the `\section` command by saying

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\expandafter\titleformat\expandafter{\csname section\endcsname}[block]
  {\bfseries\filcenter}
  {\S\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
```

Or just ignore the spurious warning.

About the output not being what you want, you should tell *what* output you're expecting.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It worked. I was expecting the section name in the center, in bold format, with the arabic symbol for section preceding it. Before using the format you suggested, I was getting just the section name with no alignment or bold-ed.